# How do I then render a function in my route using the v6 react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes

I am new to react development and currently undergoing a tutorial  on **react routes** that uses **V5 react-router-dom**. I am finding it difficult to render a function in my routes now that I am using **v6 react-router-dom**. I need help as other solutions I am seeing online advice I use hooks which I am not yet familiar with.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import DogList from './DogList';
import DogDetails from './DogDetails';
import whiskey from './images/whiskey.jpg';
import tubby from "./images/tubby.jpg";
import hazel from "./images/hazel.jpg";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    dogs: [ 
      {
        name: "Whiskey",
        age: 5,
        src: whiskey,
        facts: [
          "Whiskey loves eating popcorn.",
          "Whiskey is a terrible guard dog.",
          "Whiskey wants to cuddle with you!"
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Hazel",
        age: 3,
        src: hazel,
        facts: [
          "Hazel has soooo much energy!",
          "Hazel is highly intelligent.",
          "Hazel loves people more than dogs."
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Tubby",
        age: 4,
        src: tubby,
        facts: [
          "Tubby is not the brightest dog",
          "Tubby does not like walks or exercise.",
          "Tubby loves eating food."
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
  render() {
```

How do I then render the getDog function in my route  using the v6 react-router-dom.

```
    const getDog = props => {
      let name = props.match.params.name;
      let currentDog = this.props.dogs.find(
        dog => dog.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()
      );
      return <DogDetails {...props}  dog={currentDog}/>
    }
    return (
```

I get this error that "/dogs/Hazel" does not have an element ".
Then When I then change the **render** to **element**, I get a different error saying **Functions are not valid as a React child**.

```
     <Routes>
       <Route 
         exact
         path='/dogs'
         element={<DogList dogs={this.props.dogs} />}
       />
    

       <Route  exact path='/dogs/:name' render={getDog}/>
     </Routes>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested routes.

```js
     <Routes>
       <Route exact path='dogs' element={<DogList dogs={this.props.dogs} />}
             <Route path=':name' element={getDog}/>
       </Route>
     </Routes>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however your solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually had to use react hooks(useParams) and my code ran and worked perfectly well with no errors.

```
import { Route, Routes, useParams } from "react-router-dom";


 render() {

  const GetDogWrapper = ({props})=> {
    let  { name } = useParams();
    let currentDog = this.props.dogs.find(
         dog => dog.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()
        );
    return <DogDetails {...props}  dog={currentDog}/>
  }

return (
   <Routes>
     <Route 
       exact
       path='/dogs'
       element={<DogList dogs={this.props.dogs} />}
     />
     <Route  
        exact path='/dogs/:name' 
       element={<GetDogWrapper/> }
       />
   </Routes>  
 );
```